# string method and string modifying

Tags: java, string

I have a program and I want complete the missing code in this program in the blanks  (....)
What would it be?

```
package exr3;
public class Exr3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 ="I like ";
        String str2 ="programming ";
        String str3 ="In Java ";
        String str4;
        System.out.println(str1.length());
        str4= (.......)  ;//*how can concatenate the strings str1, str2, and str3 in str4*
        System.out.println(str4);
        str1= str1.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(str1);
        System.out.println(....);//* how can returns the index of the first occurrence of the string "Love" in str1*
    } 
}
```

Comment: Did you even attempt to just use `+` which would make perfect sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
str4 = str1+" "+str2 +" "+str3;
System.out.println(str4);
```

Comment: You don't need your extra spaces considering the strings you are adding already have them.

Comment: but how can returns the index of the first occurrence of the string "Love" in str1* in the last line?

 
          str1= str1.toLowerCase();
           System.out.println(str1);
            System.out.println(....);//*

Comment: yes i know! dude but as you know it is a bad idea to make the space inside the variable! what if we want to make that string dynamic ? then sure we'll have a little problem! for instance building SQLstatement dynamically, don't you agree ??

Comment: i have just one question! why the toLowerCase function? you need to specify the problem your problem first

Comment: `str1= str1.toLowerCase();
           System.out.println(str1);
            System.out.println(str1.substring(Love) );`  is this true now

Comment: tolowercase to convert str1 all to lower case

Comment: i did in this program more than one string methods

Comment: just tell us what do you want concatenate or compare or what ? anyway it'll give you false because you already did tolowercase so the word would be "love" and not "Love" , please be more specific

Comment: I want concatenate  str1 , str2, and str3  in str4

Comment: for tolowercaose let us forget and let us think how  can i returns the index of the first occurrence of the string "Love" in str1

Answer (score -1):

for the index problem . maybe you can try this.
`System.out.print(str1.indexOf("L"))`: